# Do the line of Apsides and Line of Nodes of the Lunar orbit ever coincide (or change their relative position and does this explain Annular eclipses?

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, moon, eclipse

In the context of solar eclipses, my understanding is  that an annular eclipse occurs when specific conditions are met, involving the relative positions of the Earth, the Moon, and the Sun. To be more precise, an annular eclipse takes place when the following conditions are fulfilled:

1. The Moon is positioned between the Sun and the Earth, corresponding to the phase of a new moon.
2. The Moon is either at or in close proximity to one of its ascending or descending nodes, essentially aligned with the plane of the ecliptic.
3. The Moon is near its apogee, signifying its farthest point in its elliptical orbit around the Earth.

My question pertains to the simultaneous fulfillment of conditions 2 and 3. Specifically, how is it possible for the Moon to be in close proximity to one of its nodes and near its apogee at the same time, and in other eclipses (total solar eclipses) the node is not near the apogee?

I suspect that the dynamic relationship between the lunar nodal and apsidal precessions might offer an explanation. The nodal line, which rotates around the Earth in the opposite direction of the Moon, completes one rotation approximately every 18.6 years. Meanwhile, the apsidal line, rotating in the same direction as the Moon, completes a rotation roughly every 8.85 Earth years. These precessions periodically align, resulting in the nodal and apsidal lines coinciding approximately every 5.99 years.

This alignment may not need to be exact for an annular eclipse to occur. Could it be that the proximity of the apogee to the nodes varies due to the changing relative positions of these lines caused by the lunar nodal and apsidal precessions?

For the sake of clarity and to facilitate a better understanding, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a diagram or animation illustrating the Moon's orbit around the Sun and the Earth's orbit around the Sun during both annular and total solar eclipses.

Comment: Cross posted to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55031/16685 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55032/16685